# How to implement gradient descent algorithms using partial derivatives?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, gradient-descent

For this question, I want to use gradient descent to minimize the function value to zero for the function x^2 + y^2 with the point (1,1) as the initial starting point. However, I get this error when I try to run my code. I'm not sure why I get that error. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks

Error: xnew = x0-alpha*grad(x0, y0)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
def f(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2

def dfdx(x,y):
    return 2*x
def dfdy(x,y):
    return 2*y

def grad(x,y):
    return [dfdx(x,y), dfdy(x,y)]

x0 = 1
y0 = 1

def grad2(f, grad, x0, y0, alpha):
    iterations = 0
    maxIterations = 1000
    while iterations < maxIterations:
        xnew = x0-alpha*grad(x0, y0)
        ynew = y0-alpha*grad(x0,y0)
        x0 = xnew
        y0 = ynew
        iterations += 1
    return xnew, ynew
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `grad2`? It looks like you are calling it with your second argument as an int. So then inside `grad2`, `grad` is an int, not a function, which gives your error. Also, FWIW, you need to use `**` instead of `^` to calculate powers in Python.

Comment: grad2(1,1,1,1,0.01) that is how I called grad2

Comment: The way you have written `grad2`, it creates a local (internal) variable called `grad`, which holds your second argument, `1`. Then when you try to call the `grad` function, you end up using this variable instead and you get that error. If you change the name of `grad` in the `def grad2():` line it should work better. But you will still have some work to do, because Python doesn't do vector/matrix multiplication the way you've implemented it in `grad()`.

Comment: So how would I be able to make those changes?

Comment: You could change `def grad2(f, grad, x0, y0, alpha)` to `def grad2(f1, grad1, x0, y0, alpha)`, `x0-alpha*grad(x0, y0)` to `x0-alpha*grad(x0, y0)[0]` and `y0-alpha*grad(x0,y0)` to `y0-alpha*grad(x0, y0)[1]`. This will avoid creating a local variable called `grad` and will apply the first component of the gradient to x and the second component to y.